# Something about navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Can someone tell me how can I move items in my navbar? I don't want to have my items aligned to right and left sides. Instead of that, I want to have offset from both sides. [This is one example of offset that I want.](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/hero.html#) This is my navbar code:

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class "container">
        <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Dom Dom</a>

         <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         </button>

        <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

            <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class = "dropdown">

                <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href = "#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Google+</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Instagram</a></li>
                </ul>                        
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- ovo su samo sign in i register gumbi-->
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href = "#">Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Register</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you not have come up with a more descriptive question title!?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to having everything the same max width, wrap everything inside:

```
<div class="container">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Everything from the navbar is already wrapped up inside the container

Comment: I managed to do it with replacing "navbar-right" with "pull-right".